# Creating View Combining Mutlibel Table Columns Wether the data exists or not - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

appreciate your help here! and open to any suggestions

I would like to create a view by joining 4 different tables. The main table is the employee  table and the rest of the tables has FK set up to the employee.id.

**Employee**
[image]
**Passport**
[image]
**Residency**
[image]
**Note**

[image]

I am experimenting with `SELECT` statement before I create the view as:

```
Select * from employee e, note n, passport p, residency r
where e.id = n.emp_id AND n.emp_id = p.emp_id AND p.emp_id = r.emp_id;
```

However, the return result is blank which I believe is obvious given that note and residency tables are empty and there are no records matching "=".

But; when I run the below I get a result back giving that both tables have a record of 1020

```
Select * from employee e, passport p
where e.id = p.emp_id;
```

any guidance and how to return all data from all tables whether the data exists or not in any of the secondary tables passport, residency, or note.

Comment: Use explicit joins rather than comma joins

Comment: @P.Salmon are you referring to LEFT JOIN

Comment: @Unis No, what P.Salmon meant was more general, to use "join" to join, and not ",". It's much more readable, and it's easier to e.g. change a join into a left join (which is, as you correctly guessed, what you need here).

Comment: @Solarflare Than you, I will try with Left Join. I am just starting to learn SQL.